# Inner join on more than 2 tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 different tables `balance`,`received`,`expenses` with following data in it.
**Table received:**

```
mysql> select * from received;
+-----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
| rid | site_id | received_amount | receive_date        |
+-----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
|   1 |       1 |             500 | 2015-08-19 18:16:51 |
|   2 |       1 |             600 | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |                                                                                                                                       
|   3 |       1 |             500 | 2015-08-20 18:16:52 |                                                                                                                                       
|   4 |       1 |             500 | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |
+-----+---------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

**Table expenses:**

```
mysql> select * from expenses;
+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
| eid | site_id | expense_amount | expense_date        |
+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
|   1 |       1 |            500 | 2015-08-19 18:17:11 |
+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------+
```

**Table balance:**

```
mysql> select * from balance;
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------+---------------------+
| transaction_id | site_id | account_title | particulars  | opening_balance | closing_balance | rid  | eid  | transaction_date    |
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------+---------------------+
|              1 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |               0 |             500 |    1 | NULL | 2015-08-19 18:16:51 |
|              2 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |             500 |            1100 |    2 | NULL | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |
|              3 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1100 |            1600 |    3 | NULL | 2015-08-20 18:16:52 |
|              4 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1100 |            1600 |    4 | NULL | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |
|              5 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1600 |            1100 | NULL |    1 | 2015-08-19 18:17:11 |
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+------+------+---------------------+
```

I am trying to merge the amount of received and expenses into balance table using following query but somehow I am not able to get correct way to get it.

```
select 
      b.transaction_id,
      b.site_id,
      b.account_title,
      b.particulars,
      b.opening_balance,
      r.received_amount,
      e.expense_amount,
      b.closing_balance,
      b.transaction_date 
   from 
      balance b 
         inner join received r 
            on b.site_id = r.site_id 
         inner join expenses e 
            on b.site_id = e.site_id 
   group by 
      b.transaction_id;
```

I am trying to get this output

```
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| transaction_id | site_id | account_title | particulars  | opening_balance | received_amount | expense_amount | closing_balance | transaction_date    |
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|              1 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |               0 |             500 |            NULL |             500 | 2015-08-19 18:16:51 |
|              2 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |             500 |             600 |            NULL |            1100 | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |
|              3 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1100 |             500 |            NULL |            1600 | 2015-08-20 18:16:52 |
|              4 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1600 |             NULL |            500 |            1100 | 2015-08-19 18:16:52 |
|              5 |       1 | test1         | test1 values |            1100 |             500 |            NULL |            1600 | 2015-08-19 18:17:11 |
+----------------+---------+---------------+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Do you mean SELECT IFNULL(var1, 0) + IFNULL(var2, 0) FROM test?

Comment: its my second requirement, my first requirement is to join the table in a way that I can show all transaction in sequence. like last output I have shown.

Comment: What is wrong with the query you just added? I ran it and it appears to return exactly what you're looking for?

Comment: No it does not works, it will provide you 500 as received_amount and 500 in expense_amount kindly check again with my data.So i posted what I suppose to have. And @DRapp given solution for the same which works like charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are somewhat close.  Instead of INNER JOIN, You need to do a LEFT-JOIN to the receipts and expenses.  Since your "Balance" table has ALL transactions, it will drive which entry it sees within your underlying support tables.  Also, don't just join on the site ID, but just the "rID" and "eID" since they would be your primary keys on the table anyhow.

No need to group by transaction ID as that is the primary key in the balance table and would only have one entry by a given ID.

```
select 
      b.transaction_id,
      b.site_id,
      b.account_title,
      b.particulars,
      b.opening_balance,
      r.received_amount,
      e.expense_amount,
      b.closing_balance,
      b.transaction_date 
   from 
      balance b 
         LEFT join received r 
            on b.rid = r.rid
            AND b.site_id = r.site_id 
         LEFT join expenses e 
            on b.eid = e.eid
            AND b.site_id = e.site_id 
   order by
      b.site_id,
      b.transaction_date
```

Comment: hehe @DRapp thanks it worked, and for left just clarifying my doubt we are just selecting all data from left table (i.e. balance) and only similar columns from other table therefore we used left join. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale, you are correct... the "LEFT-JOIN" means give me everything from the left table (Balance) first, and only IF a match on the right (receipts and expenses individually), get those too, otherwise they remain as null...